# In C how to strcmp just the beginning 2 characters and then concatenate?

Tags: c, string, string-comparison, strcmp, strncmp

In C how do I strcmp just the beginning 2 characters? Then concatenate with another string? Something like this:

```
char s[10];
scanf("%s",s);

/* if i input "cs332" or "cs234", anything start with cs */

if (strcmp("cs",???)==0)
    strcat(s,"by professor");
```

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for the `strncmp` function which is functionally identical to `strcmp` but limits the number of characters checked. So you would use it with a length of two and the comparison string of `"cs"`. But, you have a few other problems here.

First, your buffer is not big enough. There is no string that will fit into a ten-character buffer when you append the text "by professor" to it.

Secondly, robust code will *never* use `scanf` with an unbounded-string format specifier: that's asking for a buffer overflow problem. The `scanf` family is meant for formatted input and there is little more *unformatted* than user input :-)

If you want a robust input solution, see [one of my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921).

Thirdly, you should always assume that concatenating a string may overflow your buffer, and introduce code to prevent this. You need to add up:

- the current length of the string, input by the user.
- the length of the appending string ("by professor").
- one more for the null terminator.

and ensure the buffer is big enough.

The method I would use would be to have a (for example) 200-byte buffer, use `getLine()` from the linked answer (reproduced below to make this answer self-contained) with a sufficiently smaller size (say 100), then you can be assured that appending "by professor" will not overflow the buffer.

---

Function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OK       0
#define NO_INPUT 1
#define TOO_LONG 2
static int getLine (char *prmpt, char *buff, size_t sz) {
    int ch, extra;

    // Get line with buffer overrun protection.
    if (prmpt != NULL) {
        printf ("%s", prmpt);
        fflush (stdout);
    }
    if (fgets (buff, sz, stdin) == NULL)
        return NO_INPUT;

    // If it was too long, there'll be no newline. In that case, we flush
    // to end of line so that excess doesn't affect the next call.
    if (buff[strlen(buff)-1] != '\n') {
        extra = 0;
        while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF))
            extra = 1;
        return (extra == 1) ? TOO_LONG : OK;
    }

    // Otherwise remove newline and give string back to caller.
    buff[strlen(buff)-1] = '\0';
    return OK;
}
```

---

Test code:

```
// Test program for getLine().

int main (void) {
    int rc;
    char buff[10];

    rc = getLine ("Enter string> ", buff, sizeof(buff));
    if (rc == NO_INPUT) {
        // Extra NL since my system doesn't output that on EOF.
        printf ("\nNo input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (rc == TOO_LONG) {
        printf ("Input too long [%s]\n", buff);
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("OK [%s]\n", buff);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (strncmp("cs",???, 2)==0) strcat(s,"by professor");
```

Use `strncmp`

Answer (score 3):

why not directly comparing characters rather than calling strcmp?

E.g.

if(s[0]=='c' && s[1]=='s'){
...
}

Answer (score 2):

Several ways to do this.

**String comparison**:

```
if ( s[0] == 'c' && s[1] == 's' )
```

Is the naive way, as you can't expand this easily to slightly longer codes (say 3/4 characters in length).

I guess you've gathered you should be using [`strncmp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncmp.html) right?

**String Concaternation**

Don't use strcat. Really. If you concatenate two strings whose length is greater than the size of `s` (the destination) you're in trouble. Consider using [`snprint()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html) instead, like this:

```
char str[80];
snprintf(str, 80, "%s by professor", s);
```

Or, you could use [`strncat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strncat.html) as Heath points out:

```
char s[80];
strncat(s, " by professor", 80);
```

Comment: Why not strncat()?  Much faster than snprintf().

Comment: @Heath fair point, it'd work fine. I think I just reached for snprintf first.

Comment: About a year ago, I wrote my own snprintf().  It was a lot easier than I had imagined/feared.  It was also educational.  The result was less slow due to "format string parsing" than I had assumed prior to writing it.  I also didn't support anything more than ASCII/ANSI - sort of K&R sprintf() + the n that makes it snprintf().  I just wanted to share that because I encourage people to write an snprintf() for great fun.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncmp/).

Edit:

```
strcat(s,"by professor");

// s is an array of 10 characters. You need to make sure s is big enough  
// to hold the string that needs to be concatenated + to have a terminating 
// character '\0'.
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, as said, strcmp is the preferred method. Here's just a different way to do the same.

```
#define CS 29539
char s[80];

scanf("%60s", s);
if( *(short *)s == CS )
    if( strlcat(s, " by professor", sizeof(s)) >= sizeof(s) )
        fprintf(stderr, "WARNING: truncation detected: %s", s);
```

Comment: No! Please don't try this at home kids.